# Animation nodes isn't updating during rendering

Tags: animation-nodes

In animation nodes when i scrub through or play through the viewport it works and updates as it should, but when i try to render it it doesn't update, what's happening?

here's my .blend file
https://filebin.net/d8cj8xreuhbrmqpn

i'm using a setup which lets me control the fallout emission on a matrix but the matrix isn't updating when i render

Comment: could you post a screenshot or gif or .blend?

Comment: how can i export a .blend file?

Comment: just save blender it'll create blend file ctrl+s or ctrl+shift+s

Comment: ok i posted my file

Comment: light changes according to eyes? is that what you are trying to render? I don't see any animation occuring in viewport?

Comment: yes, i'm using the two spheres to control the eyes